# Fetch Value from Above Row in SQL Table and Calculate on the basis of that in next row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to Calculate Balance Quantity on the basis of top records fetched in my query.

My query is like as follows -

```
    SELECT ItemLedger.Code as Code,                                                                                                     
    ISNULL(MstOrganization.Name,'') AS OrganizationName,                                                                  
    ISNULL(stmVoucherType.Name,'') AS VoucherTypeName,                                                                                                         
    ISNULL(stmItem.Name,'') AS ItemName,                                                                                           
     ISNULL(stmItem.IsProductTag,0) AS IsProductTag,                                                                                                         
     ItemLedger.InOut AS [InOut],
     ItemLedger.ItemCode,                                                                                        
     ItemLedger.Quantity As Quantity,                                                                                                   
     CASE WHEN ItemLedger.Inout = 0    
     THEN ItemLedger.Quantity    
     ELse 0    
     End as InwardQuantity,    
      CASE WHEN ItemLedger.Inout = 1    
     THEN ItemLedger.Quantity * (-1)    
     ELse 0    
     End as OutwardQuantity,
     SUM((CASE WHEN ItemLedger.Inout = 0    
     THEN ItemLedger.Quantity    
     ELse 0    
     End) -    
      (CASE WHEN ItemLedger.Inout = 1    
     THEN ItemLedger.Quantity     
     ELse 0    
     End)) as BalanceQuantity

     FROM VIEW_ITEM_STOCK_LEDGER as ItemLedger                                                                 
     LEFT JOIN MstGroup ON MstGroup.Code = ItemLedger.GroupCode           
     LEFT JOIN MstOrganization ON MstOrganization.Code = ItemLedger.OrganizationCode                                                                       
     LEFT JOIN MstCurrency As BaseCurrency On BaseCurrency.Code = MstOrganization.CurrencyCode                                                                      
     LEFT JOIN stmVoucherType ON stmVoucherType.Code = ItemLedger.VoucherTypeCode                                                                      
     LEFT JOIN MstCurrency As DocumentCurrency ON DocumentCurrency.Code = ItemLedger.DocumentCurrencyCode                                                                      
     LEFT JOIN MstUser ON MstUser.Code = ItemLedger.UserCode                                       
     LEFT JOIN MstUOM As DetailUOM ON DetailUOM.Code = ItemLedger.DetailUOMCode                                                                      
     LEFT JOIN stmItem ON stmItem.Code = ItemLedger.ItemCode                                                                      
     LEFT JOIN MstUOM As ItemUOM ON ItemUOM.Code = stmItem.UOMCode                                                                      
     LEFT JOIN mstProductCategory ON mstProductCategory.Code = stmItem.ProductCategoryCode                                                                      
     LEFT JOIN mstTax ON mstTax.Code = ItemLedger.TaxCode                                                                                                                                                                          
     LEFT JOIN MstStockPoint ON MstStockPoint.Code = ItemLedger.StockPointCode     
     LEFT JOIN dbo.SplitCode('110,112,145,162,163,164,165,166,167,226,323,324,326,354,376') As OrgCode ON OrgCode.Code = ItemLedger.OrganizationCode                                            
     LEFT JOIN TranProductTagging ON TranProductTagging.Code = ItemLedger.ItemCode                                                                                                                  
      WHERE ((CASE WHEN 1 = 0                             
         THEN (CASE WHEN ISNULL((ItemLedger.Quantity),0) <> 0                              
           THEN 1                            
           ELSE 0                             
         END                                                                                                
           )                                                                                             
        ELSE 1                                                                                     
       END                                                                                                
      ) = 1) AND (ItemLedger.FilterDocumentDate <= '2018-10-25' AND ItemLedger.TransactionType = 0)                          
      AND ItemLedger.VoucherTypeCode not in (107,  --@AXS_VOUCHERTYPE_STOCKPOINTTRANSFER                                                          
                402, --@AXS_VOUCHERTYPE_STOCKIN                                                            
                403) --@AXS_VOUCHERTYPE_STOCKOUT                                                            
        AND StmItem.IsProductTag = 0 -- Tag Items                                                            
        AND ItemLedger.OrganizationKey Like ('' + 'AABA' + '%') AND                                 
      ((Len(ISNULL('10046406','')) > 0 AND ItemLedger.itemcode in (select * from dbo.SplitCode('10046406')))                                 
     OR Len(ISNULL('10046406','')) = 0 AND 1=1)
     group by ItemLedger.Code,MstOrganization.Name,stmVoucherType.Name,stmItem.Name,stmItem.IsProductTag,
     ItemLedger.InOut,ItemLedger.ItemCode,ItemLedger.Quantity
```

This Query is producing Output as Follows -

[image]

But, field **Balance Quantity** is fetching wrong,

My Required O/P for Balance Quantity Field -

```
BalanceQuantity
      12
      10
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience @HoneyBadger , i edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You may try with `SUM(..) OVER (PARTITTION BY ...)`. I'm not able to reproduce and test this without actual data, but you may try with this:

```
WITH ResultValues (
    Code, 
    OrganizationName, 
    VoucherTypeName, 
    ItemName, 
    IsProductTag, 
    InOut, 
    ItemCode, 
    Quantity, 
    InwardQuantity, 
    OutwardQuantity
) AS (
    -- Your statement here
)
SELECT 
    *,  
    SUM(InwardQuantity + OutwardQuantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemCode ORDER BY ItemCode) AS BalanceQuantity
FROM ResultValues
```

**Working example:**

Below is working example that demonstrates this approach:

```
DECLARE @ItemTable TABLE (
    ItemID varchar(100), 
    ItemDate date, 
    ItemIn numeric(10, 2),
    ItemOut numeric(10, 2)
);
INSERT INTO @Itemtable VALUES
('001', '2018-01-10', 10.01, 0),
('001', '2018-02-10', 10.02, 0),
('001', '2018-03-10', 10.03, 0),
('001', '2018-04-10', 0, -10.04),
('001', '2018-05-10', 10.05, 0),
('002', '2018-01-10', 20.01, 0),
('002', '2018-02-10', 20.02, 0),
('002', '2018-03-10', 20.03, 0),
('002', '2018-04-10', 20.04, 0),
('002', '2018-05-10', 20.05, 0),
('003', '2018-01-10', 30.01, 0),
('003', '2018-02-10', 0, -30.02);

SELECT 
    ItemID, 
    ItemDate, 
    ItemIn, 
    ItemOut, 
    SUM(ItemIn + ItemOut) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY ItemDate) AS ItemBalance
FROM @ItemTable
```

Output:

```
ItemID  ItemDate    ItemIn  ItemOut ItemBalance
001 2018-01-10  10.01   0.00    10.01
001 2018-02-10  10.02   0.00    20.03
001 2018-03-10  10.03   0.00    30.06
001 2018-04-10  0.00    -10.04  20.02
001 2018-05-10  10.05   0.00    30.07
002 2018-01-10  20.01   0.00    20.01
002 2018-02-10  20.02   0.00    40.03
002 2018-03-10  20.03   0.00    60.06
002 2018-04-10  20.04   0.00    80.10
002 2018-05-10  20.05   0.00    100.15
003 2018-01-10  30.01   0.00    30.01
003 2018-02-10  0.00    -30.02  -0.01
```

**Update:**

For SQL Server versions, that do not fully support `SUM(...) OVER (...)`, try with this:

```
SELECT 
    i.ItemID, 
    i.ItemDate, 
    i.ItemIn, 
    i.ItemOut, 
    (
    SELECT SUM(s.ItemIn + s.ItemOut) 
    FROM @ItemTable s 
    WHERE (i.ItemID = s.ItemId) AND (i.ItemDate >= s.ItemDate)
    ) AS ItemBalance
FROM @ItemTable i
ORDER BY i.ItemID, i.ItemDate
```

Comment: Working Example is giving Error - Incorrect syntax near 'order'

Comment: @KrunalShah I've tested this example with SQL Server 2012. Documentation says, that SUM(...) OVER (...) is supported starting with SQL Server 2008, but I can not test this.

Comment: m using Sql 2008 and its giving me error as i said.

Comment: @KrunalShah Updated answer. You may try with different working example for SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better putting the entire query in a CTE and then using `LAG`. Note that I've put comments around the `PARTITION BY` as there isn't enough information for me to infer if it is needed, or what it should be if it is:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ItemLedger.Code AS Code,
           ISNULL(MstOrganization.Name, '') AS OrganizationName,
           ISNULL(stmVoucherType.Name, '') AS VoucherTypeName,
           ISNULL(stmItem.Name, '') AS ItemName,
           ISNULL(stmItem.IsProductTag, 0) AS IsProductTag,
           ItemLedger.InOut AS [InOut],
           ItemLedger.ItemCode,
           ItemLedger.Quantity AS Quantity,
           CASE WHEN ItemLedger.Inout = 0 THEN ItemLedger.Quantity ELSE 0 END AS InwardQuantity,
           CASE WHEN ItemLedger.Inout = 1 THEN ItemLedger.Quantity * (-1) ELSE 0 END AS OutwardQuantity,
           SUM((CASE WHEN ItemLedger.Inout = 0 THEN ItemLedger.Quantity ELSE 0 END) - (CASE WHEN ItemLedger.Inout = 1 THEN ItemLedger.Quantity ELSE 0 END)) AS BalanceQuantity
    FROM VIEW_ITEM_STOCK_LEDGER ItemLedger
         LEFT JOIN MstGroup ON MstGroup.Code = ItemLedger.GroupCode
         LEFT JOIN MstOrganization ON MstOrganization.Code = ItemLedger.OrganizationCode
         LEFT JOIN MstCurrency BaseCurrency ON BaseCurrency.Code = MstOrganization.CurrencyCode
         LEFT JOIN stmVoucherType ON stmVoucherType.Code = ItemLedger.VoucherTypeCode
         LEFT JOIN MstCurrency DocumentCurrency ON DocumentCurrency.Code = ItemLedger.DocumentCurrencyCode
         LEFT JOIN MstUser ON MstUser.Code = ItemLedger.UserCode
         LEFT JOIN MstUOM DetailUOM ON DetailUOM.Code = ItemLedger.DetailUOMCode
         LEFT JOIN stmItem ON stmItem.Code = ItemLedger.ItemCode
         LEFT JOIN MstUOM ItemUOM ON ItemUOM.Code = stmItem.UOMCode
         LEFT JOIN mstProductCategory ON mstProductCategory.Code = stmItem.ProductCategoryCode
         LEFT JOIN mstTax ON mstTax.Code = ItemLedger.TaxCode
         LEFT JOIN MstStockPoint ON MstStockPoint.Code = ItemLedger.StockPointCode
         LEFT JOIN dbo.SplitCode('110,112,145,162,163,164,165,166,167,226,323,324,326,354,376') OrgCode ON OrgCode.Code = ItemLedger.OrganizationCode
         LEFT JOIN TranProductTagging ON TranProductTagging.Code = ItemLedger.ItemCode
    WHERE ((CASE
                 WHEN 1 = 0 THEN (CASE WHEN ISNULL((ItemLedger.Quantity), 0) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                 ELSE 1
            END) = 1)
      AND (ItemLedger.FilterDocumentDate <= '2018-10-25'
       AND ItemLedger.TransactionType = 0)
      AND ItemLedger.VoucherTypeCode NOT IN (107, --@AXS_VOUCHERTYPE_STOCKPOINTTRANSFER                                                          
                                             402, --@AXS_VOUCHERTYPE_STOCKIN                                                            
                                             403) --@AXS_VOUCHERTYPE_STOCKOUT                                                            
      AND stmItem.IsProductTag = 0 -- Tag Items                                                            
      AND ItemLedger.OrganizationKey LIKE ('' + 'AABA' + '%')
      AND ((LEN(ISNULL('10046406', '')) > 0
        AND ItemLedger.itemcode IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitCode('10046406') ))
        OR LEN(ISNULL('10046406', '')) = 0
       AND 1 = 1)
    GROUP BY ItemLedger.Code,
             MstOrganization.Name,
             stmVoucherType.Name,
             stmItem.Name,
             stmItem.IsProductTag,
             ItemLedger.InOut,
             ItemLedger.ItemCode,
             ItemLedger.Quantity)
SELECT CTE.OrganizationName,
       CTE.VoucherTypeName,
       CTE.ItemName,
       CTE.IsProductTag,
       CTE.InwardQuantity,
       CTE.OutwardQuantity,
       CTE.BalanceQuantity + LAG(CTE.BalanceQuantity,1,0) OVER (/*PARTITION BY ??? */ ORDER BY [Code]) AS BalanceQuantity
FROM CTE;
```

*Note: The OP has only given use a 2 row sample, I wonder is this is actually meant to be a running total, if there are 3 or more rows. Impossible to know with the limited information as well.*

Comment: Error - 'LAG' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: @KrunalShah You're *not* using SQL Server 2012+? 2008 is almost completely out of extended support, and everything else is entirely

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Comment: and yes it is a running total with more than 1000 rows, but if it works on 2 rows i l manage to do on other rows too.